# The current user in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to show the profile of the current user. 
 I have  this
Link:

```
<g:link controller="User" action="show" id=>Profile</g:link>
```

> how I do it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. You want to get the data in the controller, you want to know how to set the id in the g:link, you want to know how to show the profile in a new view...?

Comment: I want to know how to set the id in the g:link

Comment: You can find [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/link.html) how `id` is set in `g:link`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the *current* user then you should probably not rely on passing the user id in the URL but rather use whatever mechanism your security layer provides to get the logged in user id in the controller.

If your controller simply shows the profile for whichever user id it was passed in the URL then a malicious attacker could modify the URL and view the profile of a different user. To protect against that you'd need to compare the id from the URL with the one your security framework thinks is logged in, at which point you may as well just use the one the framework gave you in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Send the Profile ID of the Current User as an attribute value of

```
<g:link controller="User" action="show" id="${currentUser.id}">Profile</g:link>
```